# Чем может быть вызванная данная ошибка?

Tags: angular

Импортирую проект в stackblitz, залитый на Github. Все идет хорошо, но выдает ошибку. Все на фото. Подскажите, чем это может быть вызвано и как ее устранить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите внутрь файла. там где-то прописан путь `/dev/null` :) Вроде так

Comment: Как узнать, в каком файле прописан этот путь? Такой путь я вообще не прописывал. Да у меня на компе все работает

Comment: Добавь ошибку текстом. А так же содержимое файла `styles.scss`